# PERL extract a values from a config file

Tags: regex, linux, perl, config

I try to extract a group of values, in this case all the ips belonging to **allowed_hosts** in a config file in my linux system.
so i have this:

```
configApp.cfg
bla bla bla
    ... 
allowed_hosts = 10.121.120.163,10.121.120.164, ips, ips, more ips ...
    ...
 something .
```

I already read the web page http://perlmaven.com/how-to-extract-strings-from-a-file

but i have some issues with my scrip.

```
open(my $file, '<:encoding(UTF-8)', $config_file)
  or die "Could not open file '$config_file' $!";
while (my $row = <$file>) {
 chomp $row;
 my @strings = $row =~ /[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}\.[0-9]\{1,3\}/g;
 foreach my $s (@strings){
   print "'$s'";
 }
}
```

i hope can help me with the regex expression. Thanks

Comment: http://www.regexe.com/
I use this site to test my regex all the time!

Comment: @JReid Also try https://regex101.com/

Comment: You don't need to escape curly brackets when they're used to form a quantifier (you need to escape them only if you want to figure literal curly brackets. It is sometime useless in perl 5, but becomes mandatory in perl 6 ), the regex Perl syntax is different from the BRE syntax (Basic Regular Expression).

Comment: @PerlDog: I'm not a native speaker too. Do you think, "you don't have to" more appropriate or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is another way to do it, given your specific problem

```
use warnings 'all';
use strict;
use feature 'say';

my $file = 'configApp.cfg';

open my $fh, '<', $file or die "Can't open $file: $!";

my @allowed_hosts;

while (<$fh>) 
{
    if (/^allowed_hosts\s*=\s*(.*)/) 
    { 
        my @hosts = split /\s*,\s*/, $1; 
        push @allowed_hosts, \@hosts;
    }   
}

# Process hosts as needed
say "@$_" for @allowed_hosts;
```

Comments

- Process only the lines which have the needed `/^allowed_hosts/`
- Use the captured pattern, available in `$1`
- Store the array with results for a line as a *reference* on an array with all results
- If there is *certainly* only one `/^allowed_hosts/` line then there is no need for another array – store return from `split` directly into the `@allowed_hosts` declared outside of the loop. Then you may as well exit the loop once this line is parsed.

With multiple lines (or files), we can also use an *anonymous array*

```
if (/^allowed_hosts\s*=\s*(.*)/) 
{ 
    push @allowed_hosts, [ split /\s*,\s*/, $1 ];
}
```

However, then we cannot check the result before we stash it away, while with intermediary `@hosts` you can add checks or further validation or selection or processing if needed.

With the exact text you posted this prints

```
10.121.120.163 10.121.120.164 ips ips more ips ...
```

Answer (score 2):

It's often easier to deal with a parsing problem in pieces. Looking for IP addresses is a hard problem (just wait until someone puts an IPv6 address in there), and the file might contain other IP addresses that aren't allowed hosts. What if you pick up `abnormal_hosts = 123.234.56.78`?

Instead look for `allowed_hosts = something`. This is much easier and safer.

1. Split a `key = value` line into key and value.
2. Check if the "key" is "allowed_keys".
3. If so, split the value into IPs.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

# Simulate the contents of a file.
my @Lines = (
"configApp.cfg\n",
"bla bla bla\n",
"\n",
"dangerous_hosts = 24.45.62.1\n",
"allowed_hosts = 10.121.120.163, 10.121.120.164 ,127.0.0.1,8.8.8.8\n",
" something .\n"
);

# Don't use a foreach loop to read a file, it wastes memory.
# This is for testing only.
for my $line (@Lines) {
    chomp $line;

    # Split the line into the key and value.
    # If it isn't a key = val line there will be no key.
    my($key, $val) = split /\s*=\s*/, $line;

    # If the key isn't there, or if it isn't "allowed_hosts", skip this line.
    next if !defined $key or $key ne 'allowed_hosts';

    # Now split the IP list. Be sure to account for whitespace.
    my @ips = split /\s*,\s*/, $val;

    say "Allowed Hosts: @ips";

    # We found the line, no need to read the rest of the file.
    last;
}
```

Note there is no need to parse IP addresses. All the program cares is that it's a comma separated list. If you want you can verify the contents of `@ips`, but now you can do it one at a time without having to parse everything else on the line.

Also note that I always made sure to account for possible whitespace around things like `=` and `,`. People get really inconsistent about where they put spaces.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this:

```
open(my $fh, '<', $config_file)
    or die "Could not open file '$config_file': $!";

while(<$fh>) {
    next until /^allowed_hosts = /;
    my @ips = /\d+[^\s,]+/g;
    print join "\n", @ips;
    last;
}
```

The `next until` discards quickly all the lines until the good one is found.
All matches are stored in the `@ips` variable.
Note that since you already know that this line contains ips, you don't need to build an explicit pattern to describe an ip, you only need to avoid whitespaces and commas.
`last` stops the loop.
There's many chances you don't need to add an encoding information to open your file, since it is probably entirely written with ASCII characters as many config files, but I can be wrong.

Note, if you want to make the results available outside of the loop, you must declare the `@ips` variable outside of the loop (before it).

Comment: Simple and great. Suggestion: if the input contains more than one `allowed_hosts` line, then you could replace `my @ips = /\d+[^\s,]+/g;` with `push @ips, /\d+[^\s,]+/g;` and drop the `last;` line. But your pattern is awesome. :-)

Comment: `/^allowed_hosts = /` will not work with `allowed_hosts=` or any other amount of spaces. Because humans are very inconsistent about spacing, for any sort of hand-written format use `\s*`.

Comment: @Schwern: Your remark is correct, but I prefer to stick to the information given in the question. The author is then free to adapt the code to make it more flexible (at little expense).

Answer (score 0):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Config::Simple; # you may have to install this one

my $cfg = Config::Simple->new(configApp.cfg);

my @hosts = split " ", $cfg->param('allowed_hosts');
```

had the list been separated bit comma's rather then spaces, the last line would even be more readable like:

```
my @hosts = $cfg->param('allowed_hosts');
```

Answer (score -1):

Do it in two steps. First extract the ip address/host name list then use split to get the individual entries

```
if( $row =~ /^\s*allowed_hosts\s*=\s*(.*)/ ) {
  foreach my $s (split(/\s*,\s*/,$1)) {
    print("allowed: $s\n");
  }
}
```

If you don’t want to do that you could try this:

```
while(my $row = <$file>) {
  chomp;
  print("'$_'\n") foreach (split(/\s*,\s*/,($row =~ /^\s*allowed_hosts\s*=\s*(.*)/i)[0]));
}
```